# 10k by 10k matrix malloc curiousity in c

Tags: c, matrix, malloc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to sum a large number of float number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148149/how-to-sum-a-large-number-of-float-number)

I have a matrix 'x' that is 10,000 elements by 10,000 elements.

In the first case I declare the matrix like:

```
int n = 10000;
unsigned int size_M = n*n;
unsigned int mem_size_M = sizeof(int)*size_M;
int* x = (int*)malloc(mem_size_M);
```

Step (1) The matrix is initialized:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        x[i*n+j] = 1;
```

Step (2) Sum the elements of the matrix and print the total:

```
for(i=0i<n;i++)
    for(j=0j<n;j++)          
        sum +=x[i*n+j];

printf("sum: %d \n", sum);
```

As I would expect the above code prints 'sum: 100000000 '.

However if I declare the matrix like:

```
int n = 10000;
float size_M = n * n;
float mem_size_M = sizeof(float) * size_M;
float* x = (float*)malloc(mem_size_M);
```

And again perform the steps 1 and 2 the correct answer is not printed out, but '16777216' instead. Why is this?

ANSWER: To get the appropriate answer do a type conversion...

```
sum +=(int)x[i*n+j];
```

Comment: Are you trying to print a `float` with `%d` instead of `%f`?

Comment: Looks like you're running into the machine epsilon for floating point numbers. Suggested reading: [What Every Computer Scientist should know about floating Point Numbers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148149/how-to-sum-a-large-number-of-float-number

Comment: If you have a spare hour or two to kill, read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). It will literally make you rethink how floating point numbers "work" if  you're not familiar already.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of the precision limitations of the float type. You can't just add 1.0 to float with value > 16777216 (2^24), but you can add 2.0, or 0.1:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float f = 16777220;
    printf("f = %f\n", f + 1);
    printf("f = %f\n", f + 2);
    printf("f = %f\n", f + 0.1);
    return 0;
}
```

The [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) standard floating-point numbers have have 4 bytes, consisting of a sign bit, an 8-bit excess-127 binary exponent, and a *23-bit mantissa*. It's a bit complicated to explain precisely why it happens, but I can say that this is a extreme case when operation error reaches its maximum.